# How to group the result of a SQL Server query (group by not working)

Tags: sql-server, group-by

Got this query:

```
SELECT TOP 100 
    i.item_id , 
    i.item_description, 
    part.part_number 
FROM 
     i 
LEFT JOIN 
     part ON part.item_id = i.item_id
```

An item usually have multiple part number. It is possible to modify my query to get a grouped result? 
without to add any subselects. Group by is not working. I tried to add `FOR XML PATH('')` but it transform all columns in xml, not only part number

Comment: You are looking for a `GROUP_CONCAT` or `LISTAGG` [workaround](http://stackoverflow.com/q/451415/314291). Sql Server doesn't have a simple "String.Join" function FWR.

Comment: First of all this looks like a desing issue. I think that there should be a 1:n relation between an item-table and a part-table. Anyway, I'll provide an exampel soon

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a possible way (still I think you should use a 1:n design)

```
DECLARE @items TABLE(item_id INT, item_description VARCHAR(100),part_number VARCHAR(100));
INSERT INTO @items VALUES(1,'HP Color','C4149A-REMAN')
                        ,(1,'HP Color','C4149REMAN')
                        ,(2,'Toner','480-0055')
                        ,(2,'Toner','4800055')
                        ,(2,'Toner','888037')
                        ,(3,'anotherone','1234');
WITH itemCTE AS
(
    SELECT DISTINCT item_id,item_description
    FROM @items
)                        
SELECT itemCTE.*,parts.list 
FROM itemCTE
CROSS APPLY
(
    SELECT STUFF((SELECT ', ' + part_number AS concated
                  FROM @items AS itm 
                  WHERE itm.item_id=itemCTE.item_id
                  FOR XML PATH(''),TYPE).value('.','varchar(max)'),1,2,'')
) AS parts(list)
```

Comment: I tried to run your code but I got this: Error Code: 1087, SQL State: S0002]  Must declare the table variable "@items".

Comment: Did you copy the whole part?

Comment: Well, the DECLARE in the first line does the job. You can run this against your own table simply by changing @items to the real name of your table, Please tick as accepted, if this solves your problem, thx

Comment: I've maked some little canges and it worked, tnx